# Storing Responses for Class Objects [C#]

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, constructor, c#-3.0

I've been trying to come up with correct way to store a instructors name and numbers into their respective class objects

Teacher _teacher;
Student[] students;

These are inside a class called Course.

Once I've gather all the necessary responses, then I need to instantiate a Course objects the values that matches to Course constructor. I am unable to figure to pass in the correct data type that the constructor requires.

```
class Course
{
    // Fields for a course - title, description, teacher, students
    private string _title;
    private string _description;
    private Teacher _teacher = null;
    private Student[] _students;

    public Course(string title, string description, Teacher teacher, Student[] student)
    {
        _title = title;
        _description = description;
        _teacher = teacher;
        _students = student;
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set { _title = value; }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get { return _description; }
        set { _description = value; }
    }

    public Teacher Instructor
    {
        get { return _teacher; }
        set { _teacher = value; }
    }

    public Student[] Students
    {
        get { return _students; }
        set { _students = value; }
    }
}
```

}

```
    public static void CreateCourse(Course _currentCourse)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("test");

        if (_currentCourse !=  null )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("* Create Course *\r\n");

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the course title: ");
            string title = Console.ReadLine();
            Validation.EmptyValidation(title,
                "Please, do not leave the course title field empty!" +
                "\r\nEnter the course title: ");


            Console.WriteLine("Enter the course description: ");
            string description = Console.ReadLine();
            Validation.EmptyValidation(title,
            "Please, do not leave the course description field empty!" +
            "\r\nEnter the course description: ");

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the course instructor: ");
            string instructor = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of students in the course: ");
            string students = Console.ReadLine();
            int.TryParse(students, out int stu);

        }
    }

class Student : Person
{
    // Field for a student grade.
    int _grade;

    // Student constructor
    public Student(string name, string description, int age, int grade ) : base(name, description, age)
    {
        _grade = grade;
    }

    // Accessor & Mutator for the Student grade.
    public int Grade
    {
        get { return _grade; }
        set { _grade = value; }
    }
}

class Teacher : Person
{
    // Field for the teacher knowledge
    private string[] _teacherKnowledge;

    // Teacher constructor
    public Teacher(string name, string description, int age, string[] teacherKnowledge) : base(name, description, age)
    {
        _teacherKnowledge = teacherKnowledge;
    }

    // Accessor & Mutator for the the Teacher knowledge
    public string[] Knowledge
    {
        get { return _teacherKnowledge; }
        set { _teacherKnowledge = value; }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do the Teacher and Student classes look like? You need to instantiate a Teacher an `stu` instances of Student. By the way, you'll probably be happier with `Students` being a `List<Student>` rather than a array of students.

Comment: @Flydog57 I edited my response to include both teacher and student class.

Comment: Can not you create instances of Teacher and Student classes?

Comment: What is the problem? to create a Course, you will:
1. create a Teacher ("name", "desc", 25, new string[] {"knowledge1"})`
2. create List of Students `new Student[2]{new Student("name", "desc", 12, 1), new Student("name2", "desc2", 12, 1)}`
3. finally create a `Course("title", "desc", TheTeacherVariable, StudentsVariable)`

Comment: I think you're a half way, simply you need to create a loop to start creating the student objects one by one and assign them into an `Array` or `List`. if you have a single teacher, then just a strightaway a single object creation.